# Making a utilities class for frequently used colors etc in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subclass

I am making a utilities class that among other frequently used code have some methods for returning colors. However `UIColor` class is a part of UIKit so I wonder should I import UIKit to this subclass of NSObject, or should I return an `id`? Or are there other options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a subclass I use a UIColor category for custom colors

something like this:

```
@implementation UIColor (CustomColors)

+ (UIColor *)mb_toolBarTintColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:0.5 saturation:0.1 brightness:0.3 alpha:1];
}

@end
```

and then I can use it with a simple

```
[self.toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor mb_toolBarTintColor]];
```

Comment: Forgot one thing, do I need to import UIKit or this category where I shall use it?

Comment: UIKit is included in the iOS project prefix.pch anyway. So no need to import it again.

Comment: Though I am not a big fan of categories, this seems to be a good example of perfectly reasonable usage of a category.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass always needs to import the super. Make your subclass a direct subclass of `UIColor`, and then import the superclass, or the entire kit in the .h file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply make a .h file that has a bunch of #define values for constants, such as:

```
#define TEXT_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8f green:0.8f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0f]
```